# Rails: Send put method from a index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, methods

I want do be able do update some values direct form the index view of my subscription Resource.

To do so I try the following code:

```
subscription_path(subscription, :method => :put)
```

The problem is, that this goes directs to the show action as if the method would be :get!

Thanks for your help!
Maechi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're wanting to show a form for editing Subscriptions on the Subscriptions index page. Assuming that you have a `@subscription` variable in scope that represents an existing Subscription record you want to edit, you should be able to do:

```
<% form_for @subscription do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

—which will submit a PUT request to your controller's `update` action.

Comment: I just want to update something from the overview page - I guess that this is not restful, so this might not be allowed... Thanks although

Comment: Ah, ok I see your point... so I will do a form although there is only a button in it...! Thanks

Comment: Yes you need a `form_for` or a `remote_form_for`.